# Upload to Youtube using API v3 and Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, api, youtube

I am trying to use Ruby to upload a video to youtube using simple http request but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. 
Here's the code:

```
require 'httparty'
token = 'blahblah'
filename = 'video.mp4'
headerinfo = {
    'Host' => 'www.googleapis.com',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' + token,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-Upload-Content-Length' => File.size(filename).to_s,
    'X-Upload-Content-Type'  => 'video/mp4'
    }


HTTParty.post('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,status',
    :header => headerinfo,
    :data =>{
        'snippet' =>{
            'title' => 'My test video from Ruby',
            'description' => 'nice video'
        },
        'status' =>{
            'embeddable' => true,
            'privacyStatus' => 'public',
            'license' => 'youtube'
        }
    }.to_json,
    :media => (File.open(filename,'rb').read)

    )
```

The error is as follows:

```
{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"required", "message"=>"Login Required", "locationType"=>"header", "location"=>"Authorization"}
```

Token is correct as i tested it on another python based application and it works. So what am i doing wrong?

Note: i tried using the google api library as well but couldn't get it to work. It doesn't mention properly regarding where to provide the token id etc. I created client_secrets.json file with all other necessary info but am still not sure where to specify the token. Here is the code provided by Google: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

Either should be fine for me but would be great if i could get it to work via a simple post request.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `:headers => headerinfo` instead of `:header...`. That appears to be the correct key, according to [this example](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/headers_and_user_agents.rb)